# Can't reload the page after many requests

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm parsing a website with ruby nokogiri, but after many requests the sites blocks me, so I have to retry at the last page I was parsing (the link is get by the @next_link).

I've tried using the `sleep` method, exceptions e many things. Nothing works.

I have, for example, 150 pages to parse, but at page 25 I get blocked.

This function makes a loop through my pages:

```
def final_results(range, link)
  (range[:start]..range[:finish]).each do |page_number|
    begin
      if page_number == 1
        parse_response(parser('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1'))
      elsif page_number == 2
        get_next_link(link)
      else
        get_next_link(@next_link)
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      range = {:start => page_number, :finish => range[:finish]}
      final_results(range, link)
    end
  end
end
```

This function gets the next page link and parses the current page:

```
def get_next_link(link)
  begin
    post((BASE_URL + link), request_with_captcha_solution)
    aux = parser('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')
    parse_response(aux)
    paginator_table = aux.css('table.fonte11')[1].children[1]
    @next_link = paginator_table.children[3].children[-2]['href']
  rescue Exception => e
    @error_message ="#{$!}"
  end
  @next_link
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely being blocked because the website you're scraping does not want bots consuming its pages at the high rate you're attempting. Slowing down your scraping is a reasonable approach, and you should be able to accomplish this with a `sleep` between each page. You'll have to use trial and error to figure how slowly you need to go so that you don't get blocked.

Something like this should work:

```
def final_results(range, link)
  (range[:start]..range[:finish]).each do |page_number|
    begin
      if page_number == 1
        parse_response(parser('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1'))
      elsif page_number == 2
        get_next_link(link)
      else
        get_next_link(@next_link)
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      range = {:start => page_number, :finish => range[:finish]}
      final_results(range, link)
    end
    # sleep here!
  end
end
```

Comment: I' ve tried this before, even with 1 minute sleep didnt work.

Comment: It's possible, then, that the rate-limiting mechanism locks you out for a while after a burst of requests. You could try using a VPN to hit it from different IP addresses, but this is a little "shady". The operator of the site doesn't want you to crawl it like this. Question: When the the requests fail, what status code are you getting in the response?